# What is rules in firebase? & What $ mean in the value incode?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

What does `$uid` mean in the code ?

is `$uid` a column name or key name?

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a documentation that is exposed to public https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data)

> A wildcard path used to represent ids and dynamic child keys.

more detail , let say you have this data

```
{
   users : {
      "SOME_KEY_1" : {"name" : 'test 1' , "private" : {...}} ,
      "SOME_KEY_2" : {"name" : 'test 2' , "private" : {...}} ,
      "SOME_KEY_3" : {"name" : 'test 3' , "private" : {...}} ,
   }
}
```

and these rule

```
{
   "rules" : {
       "users" : {
           "$uid" : {
                "private" : "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

you cannot know the keys of `users` node but you need to prevent other users to `private` node except their own so you put `$uid` to represent dynamic child keys

---

in your case you just allowing user to write to their own data

Comment: Thanks @Ali, i got it!!